# Docker get-started tutorial, port 3000 does not run the app

Tags: docker

I am new to Docker and I am following their official tutorial - https://docs.docker.com/get-started/.

I am trying to start my container with this command -  `docker run -dp 3000:3000 getting-started`.

However, when I am trying to open my browser to `http://localhost:3000` I get
[image]

I already did try to run it on different port - `docker run -dp 3000:80 getting-started`, however it redirects me to docker tutrial page and thats not what I want.

I have created a file `app/Dockerfile` with this content:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM node:12-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache python3 g++ make
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install --production
CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
```

I can't find the problem and I will be grateful for help.

Comment: Is your web app running on port `80` inside the container? Can you `curl localhost:80` from within?

Comment: when I `curl localhost:80` I get a DOM of apache2.

Comment: `docker run -d -p 3000:80 getting-started` should map port `80` on the container to port `3000` on the host.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't tell me how to resolve my issue :(

Comment: Try to run the application on a different port than 80 in the container, and map it. For example, port 5600. Just to lower chances of another app running on the same port.

Comment: What is running on port `3000` inside the container? Nothing, right? The webserver youre using runs on port `80` as far as i understand?

Comment: @Manu The left side is the host container, 80 is the container one.

Comment: @Maroun correct, so what you said should solve the problem. I don't understand why map the container port `3000`. EDIT: Nevermind, i see youre already trying with `-p 3000:80`. Maybe something is wrong with your firewall regarding ports?

Comment: When I run curl localhost:3000 I get -> `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection broken by the other party`

Comment: Basically what the error says is that the webserver running inside docker is reachable for your machine but the connection could not be fully established and was reset. So i guess it must be some kind of networking error. Maybe try a fresh start by restarting your machine and creating the docker container again. Also make sure to check your firewall

Comment: It should be `docker run -dp 80:80 docker/getting-started` I guess you missed the right image name, you might also have a running version of apache on port 80, so you can select another port `docker run -dp 30000:80 docker/getting-started`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you ever solved this but I had a similar issue as I missed this all important line located in [this section](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/#build-the-apps-container-image):

"If you haven't already done so, open a terminal and ***go to the app directory*** with the Dockerfile"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and this is how i fixed it. There are two Dockerfiles, one in the getting started folder and the other(the one you created). in the app folder. if you run and build the container in the app directory you'll get that error message. However if you run and build in the app directory, it should run successfully.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your Dockerfile, as did mine in my http://localhost/tutorial/our-application/ does not have the

```
EXPOSE 3000
```

line at the end, whereas this line indeed appears in the Dockerfile in https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/#build-the-apps-container-image (link provided in pbay's answer).

Without that line, the produced container does not expose port 3000, and docker start -dp 3000:(whatever) is bound to fail. *[Edit: that's my understanding as a near-absolute beginner, but other people seem to have run that container successfully without that line. Go figure why/how. I'm ready to be enlightened.]* In "Docker Desktop" on Windows, you can see in the dashboard that the container exits as soon as it starts.

I added that EXPOSE 3000 line, rebuild and rerun the using the same commands as first time:

```
docker build -t getting-started .
docker -dp 3000:3000 getting-started
```

and it now works fine.

(*Rant: "If you've created Dockerfiles before, you might see a few flaws in the Dockerfile below" they say. Well this is not a minor flaw -- this is a beginner-discouraging trap. How come ?*)

Comment: The version of the tutorial I'm following, has that `EXPOSE 3000` instruction, but I still have the same error. https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/